# Header alloca.h in Windows

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, gcc, alloca

I can't see any `alloca.h` equivalent in `Visual C 2010`. How can one perform stack allocation in `Visual C` on Windows? I miss the function `alloca`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [`_alloca`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx). Visual C uses an _ prefix for non-standard functions in the C headers.

Comment: It would be worth noting that `_alloca` is in header `<malloc.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no alloca.h in windows. You should

```
#include <malloc.h>
```

instead. The alloca function is there